# creating https actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I am working asp.net mvc3. I  have an action link like following:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Yes", "Admin", "Foo", null, new { @class = "link" })
```

How can I modify this to create a link in https as oppose to http as I have set my controller action with [RequireHttps]

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/05/adding-httpsssl-support-to-aspnet-mvc-routing/)

Comment: What does your route definition look like?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ever looked at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx) or the Intellisense that Visual Studio offers you?

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Yes",                     // linkText
    "Admin",                   // actionName
    "Foo",                     // controllerName
    "https",                   // protocol
    null,                      // hostName
    null,                      // fragment
    null,                      // routeValues
    new { @class = "link" }    // htmlAttributes
)
```

Comment: Saucer of milk, table 2